# ASP.NET Core Web API - AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've been looking at this, but still cannot find a solution, here goes:

To return all players, I will pass in something similar to:
http://localhost:7777/api/teams/34fe3b6f-ba23-4657-820a-6c59dd49173a/players

To return a specific player on a specific team, I will pass in somethign similar to:
http://localhost:7777/api/teams/34fe3b6f-ba23-4657-820a-6c59dd49173a/players/f7de7974-9cbb-4c2c-884e-29036d6c2d76

I keep getting the following error:
System.ArgumentException: 'The route parameter name 'id' appears more than one time in the route template. '

Could someone please advise how to fix this?

```
[Route("api/Teams/{Id}/Players}")]
[ApiController]
public class PlayersController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAllTeamPlayers(Guid id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTeamPlayer(Guid id, Guid id2)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the route parameters like this:

```
[Route("api/Teams/{teamId}/}")]
[ApiController]
public class PlayersController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("players")]
    public IActionResult GetAllTeamPlayers([FromRoute] Guid teamId)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet("players/{playerId}")]
    public IActionResult GetTeamPlayer([FromRoute] Guid teamId, [FromRoute] Guid playerId)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: You legend, that's great!